# Sqlconnection why try catch need message

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I have this class to open  a connection.

```
 public static SqlConnection GetConnection()
    {
        string str3 = "Data Source= 10.161.2.110 ;Initial Catalog =eplo;uid =sa;pwd = tudo";
        SqlConnection abre3 = new SqlConnection(str3);
        abre3.Open();
        return abre3;
    }
```

Works fine , but when can not connect i need somethin to return a message showing the connection is not posible

late i call this class in a form :

```
private SqlConnection interna = Tconex.GetConnection();
```

Comment: Why not just catch the exception at the place where you are trying to use the connection? Also, are you sure you want to store the connection in a form? As a rule, one is normally better off creating a connection when needed and then closing it again ASAP, to let the built-in connection pooling handle the underlying connections for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
private SqlConnection interna;

try
{
    interna = Tconex.GetConnection();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.Writeline("Failed to connect: ", ex.Message);
}
```

If it were up to me, I'd create a database wrapper:

```
public class GhettoDbWrapper
{
    string connectionString;

    public GhettoDbWrapper(string serverInstanceName, string databaseName)
    {
        // Create connection string
    }

    public ExecuteGhettoDb(string query)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionSting))
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Connection failed: ", ex.Exception);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Ghetto throw the rest of them
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your connection class in a try/catch that rethrows the SqlException:

```
private const string SQL_CONN_STR = "Data Source= 10.161.2.110 ;Initial Catalog =eplo;uid =sa;pwd = tudo";

public static SqlConnection GetConnection() {
  try {
    return new SqlConnection(SQL_CONN_STR);
  } catch (SqlException err) {
    throw new Exception("The connection is not possible.", err);
  }
}
```

Now, in your form or other piece of code that calls this static method, wrap that in a try/catch routine that displays the error:

```
// in your code:
private void Connect() {
  SqlConnection conn = null;
  try {
    conn = GetConnection();
  } catch (Exception err) {
    MessageBox.Show(this, err.Message, "Connection Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
  }
  if (conn != null) {
    // more code
  }
}
```

Further, if you wanted to log or inspect the underlying **SqlException**, you could add something to check the **InnerException**:

```
  Console.WriteLine("Connection SqlError: " + err.InnerException.Message);
```